# Java - Endless loop with ListIterator .hasNext()

Tags: java, arraylist, infinite-loop, listiterator

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("test");

while(list.listIterator().hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(list.listIterator().next());
}
```

This generates an endless loop of lines with "test". Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: You are generating a new iterator at each loop step so as it is always brand new and your list contains an item, `hasNext()` always returns `true`.

Comment: you can alternatively do it in one line when you use a for loop: `for (ListIterator<String> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext();) { /* looped code */ }`, limits the scope of the iterator to just that loop.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The iterator created for hasNext is not the same that is for next.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("test");
Iterator listIterator = list.listIterator()
while(listIterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(listIterator.next());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are creating a new iterator on each loop, the newly created iterator pointer will be positioned before the first element in the List. `hasNext()` method in that case will always return true and `next()` method will return the first element in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
System.out.println(list.listIterator().next());
```

you create an new iterator each time you try to print out the next element.

Just try the following:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("test");

Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()) {

    System.out.println(it.next());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ListIterator<String> litr = null;
list.add("test");
litr=list.listIterator();
System.out.println("Elements in forward directiton");
while(litr.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(litr.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create new instance of iterator in every `list.listIterator()` call.

Create list iterator once, before loop starts to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your calling **listIterator** everytime. Try assign to a variable and loop over that.

Answer (score 0):

`list.listIterator()` returns new Iterator. Below is source of AbstractList

```
  public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
        return listIterator(0);
    }
  public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int location) {
        return new FullListIterator(location);
    }
```

You should make loop like this,

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("test");
Iterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();
while(iterator .hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're creating new iterator at each `list.listIterator()` call. All the new instances will be at the beginning of the iterator. You can fix it if you use the same iterator:

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("test");

    Iterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
```